# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

When the HTTP request execute the select SQL to query some data, the exception occurs. I am using the dynamic datasource, Spring 3.2.4, MySQL. The exception occurs sometime, not often. I think that I use dynamic incorrectly. After set datasource, I clear the datasource in the threadlocal. So what's the problem?

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@5dc9c56d] for key [com.jd.official.core.dao.datasource.DynamicDataSource@3c572554] bound to thread [http-1601-2]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:241) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:350) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at $Proxy144.selectByMap(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.jd.common.springmvc.interceptor.SecurityMobileAuthorityInterceptor.preHandle(SecurityMobileAuthorityInterceptor.java:132) [SecurityMobileAuthorityInterceptor.class:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:951) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:853) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [?:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@5dc9c56d] for key [com.jd.official.core.dao.datasource.DynamicDataSource@3c572554] bound to thread [http-1601-2]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:163) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
... 37 more
```